# PHP imagick with PDF issue

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I am trying to convert the first page of a PDF to an image file.

I have the following code:

```
$im = new imagick('/images/test.pdf[0]');

$im->setImageFormat("jpg");
$page=$im->queryFormats();
echo "<pre>";
 print_r ($page);
echo "</pre>";
```

However, I get an error message saying:

`Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image`

If I change:

`$im = new imagick('/images/test.pdf[0]');`

to:

`$im = new imagick('/images/test.pdf');`

I get  the following error:

`Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file`

I am sure the path to my PDF is correct and I'm not sure how to solve this. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `/images` folder in the ROOT of your drive? Remember - imagick is running within PHP and has no clue whatsoever what your site's URL-space structure is. You need to use the local file system path, e.g.

```
$im = new imagick('/path/to/example.com/html/images/test.pdf[0]');
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I did try http*://mysite/images/test.pdf and still not working. +1 though.

Comment: using a url isn't going to work. you'd be doing a full-blown http request to your own server, and that's highly inefficient. what does `var_dump(is_readable('/images/test.pdf'))` show? if it's boolean false, then you've definitely got a bad path.

Comment: I have tried var_dump(is_readable('/images/test.pdf')) and it showed false. However, I added echo "<a href='/images/test.pdf'>test</a>"; in the next line and I can click it and open it. why?

Comment: because like I said, `/images` is like `c:\images` as far as php/imagick are concerned. you need to use a FILESYSTEM path, not a web url-type path.

Comment: I face the same problem, too.
Even though var_dump(is_readable('/images/test.pdf')) returns true, 
I get the same error.